# Codeigniter - How can I load a search page simply clicking in the search field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm looking to create a search function in CodeIgniter.
My view file has been splitted in two parts:

**Header part**, that contains the search bar

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/live_search');?>
    <div class="toolbar-icon-bg hidden-xs" id="toolbar-search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="ti ti-search"></i></button></span>
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="ti ti-close"></i></button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

**Body part**, that contains the result of the search.

```
<div class="static-content-wrapper">
                <div class="static-content">
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">

                            <li class=""><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="active">Search</li>

                        </ol>
                        <div class="container-fluid">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="panel panel-white">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h2><!-- Panel --></h2>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                            <div id="update"><!-- search results will be added here --></div>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="panel-footer">
                                            <span class="text-gray"><em>Footer</em></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div> <!-- .container-fluid -->
                    </div> <!-- #page-content -->
                </div>
```

In my controller I've written the following code:

```
public function live_search()
    {

        //load page template    
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates/live_search');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

I would like to "activate" the "live_search" public function simply selecting the search field. Just to give you an example, you can think to the search function of Netflix. When you select the search bar, a black page is loaded automatically and start typing you see the results of your search.

So, when I select the search text field my script should load the "templates/live_search" page.

How could I do this? 
Thanks for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation like this isn't done in CodeIgniter on the server, its done client site in JS. You need JS to listen for the search input focus, and then either AJAX in your "live search page" (not exactly clear on what you want there), or load everything on initial page load, and then just show the "live search page" on focus of the search bar.

If you're using jQuery it might look something like this:

```
$('body').on("focus","#search",function(){
  $('.live-search-container').show()
  //or do an ajax call
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply. I'm sorry but I didn't understand. I'm really new to jQuery so I ask you to be a little bit more specific. Where should I apply this part of code, in my footer?

Comment: What he wants to say is that this types of things are not handled in server side. You can already load your view for search and keep it hidden (`display: none`). When user user focuses on your search button, `$('.live-search-container').show()` will remove the `display: none` so it would be visible.

Comment: You could put it in the footer of your view, yes, inside a set of <script> tags. Remember this code isn't PHP, its Javascript, which is run in the browser.

Comment: Hello guys, I don't know why Stackoverflow didn't notify me your new replies. I'm still having trouble, so I'm starting to think that I'm doing something wrong. I apologize for this...I'm good to develop in PHP/MySQL and HTML, but I'm not so ok on using javascript. I'm going to put some more details of my code in my thread so maybe you can see in detail what I would like to do. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Something like this can only be done in Javascript, so try posting whatever JS code you have.